# Flutter ListView Selecting item by dragging

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

Just wondering if anyone has any idea on how to do this. I have a horizontal listview in a Flutter application which contains images. I would like to implement a swiping mechanism so when I swipe the middle image will be selected.

I tried GestureDetector but it didnt go well with the ListView, I also tried Listener, but with that I only got the position of the pointer.

Is there a way to implement a mechanism like this?

**This is the listView what I currently have:**
[image]

**and here is the code for it:**

```
new Listener(
    onPointerMove: (opm) {
      print("onPointerMove .. ${opm.position}");
    },
    child: ListView.builder(
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        EdgeInsets padding = index == 0
            ? const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 20.0, right: 10.0, top: 4.0, bottom: 30.0)
            : const EdgeInsets.only(
                left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 4.0, bottom: 30.0);

        return new Padding(
          padding: padding,
          child: new InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              print('Card selected${index}');
            },
            onLongPress: () {
              print('Card long selected${index}');
            },
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage:
                  ExactAssetImage('assets/img_${index % items.length}.jpg'),
              minRadius: 15,
              maxRadius: 60,
              //radius: 30,
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: items.length,
    ));
```

Comment: http://rrtutors.com/description/Flutter-Drag&Drop-Listview-Reorderable-Listview

Answer (score 0):

GestureDector is your choice

Wrap CircleAvatar in GestureDetector

```
      GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragStart: (_) { /* do selection logic */},
        child: CircleAvatar(
          backgroundImage:
              ExactAssetImage('assets/img_${index % items.length}.jpg'),
          minRadius: 15,
          maxRadius: 60,
          //radius: 30,
        ),
      ),
```

If you still want to have InkWell effect you cat left it there

But If you wrap GestureDetector in InkWell or vica versa and listen to same geture (onTap for example) only one widget will get that gesture callback fired